# There was no endpoint listening at http://169.254.2.2:8000/calculator/Calculator

Tags: wcf

I am getting the below errror when calliong WCF method from windows mobile.

> There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://169.254.2.2:8000/calculator/Calculator that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.

- I am able to ping to mobile
- Port # 8000 is enabled in my PC Firewall.
- I used the basichttpbinding both PC and Mobile side.

Still i am not able to call method from WCF service.

Comment: Is there actually a service listening on that port?  It may be open on the firewall, but it needs to be active on the server as well.

Answer (score 1):

I also got the error "There was no endpoint listening at 'x'" after working on with my client/server setup all morning. My firewall was off, so I tried a few things but nothing seemed to eliminate this problem. Finally I decided to restart my PC and that must have liberated the port. I believe that the port got hung up by me not closing the service connection properly before exiting the application. Anyway, restarting allowed me to connect to the same endpoint again with no further problems.